# Ubuntu 14.04 screenshots with LXDE

Tags: 14.04, lxde

Recently I replaced Unity with LXDE on my Ubuntu 14.04. Experience so far is pretty good, a lot of troubles with Unity before have gone.

One thing missing though, I regularily used Shift+PrintScreen to capture some part of the screen. It worked before with Unity, but now it doesn't work any more on LXDE. Anyone has an idea how to make it work on LXDE? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How thoroughly did you "replace Unity with LXDE"? I'm asking because it isn't clear which program you're using to get the screen capture.

In a pure LXDE situation --- Lubuntu is the LXDE+Openbox distro supported here as an official flavor --- `scrot` is the default program to take screenshots.

`man scrot` has this:

```
-s, --select  
  Interactively select a window or rectangle with the mouse.
```

It's then up to you to set up the appropriate keybinds in your `rc.xml` file (or whatever it's called) which should be in `~/.config/openbox`. And you can read about rc.xml [here](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Configuration).

I have separate keybindings for instant and time-delayed screenshots. I haven't set up binding for interactive selection because I rarely need that and prefer to keep a copy of the full screen for "legal" reasons. In any case, setting up a keybind for a specific purpose is simple.

But here's one way using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>

```
<keybind key="S-Print">        # Interactive
  <action name="Execute"><command>scrot -s -q 100 ~/Pictures/%Y%m%d%H%M%S.png</command></action>
</keybind>
```

In this,

- `-s` enables the interactive mode
- `q 100` produces the best quality image while `75` is the default
- ~/Pictures/%Y%m%d%H%M%S.png is the filename using `strftime` (explained in `man strftime`). Of course, you can choose another destination folder or filename.

And I guess it isn't necessary to point out that Lubuntu is a "slim" distro and may not have all the facilities that distros with DEs such as Unity, GNOME, KDE, or MATE offer.

Comment: I've gone through some of your other questions here and notice that you already have an experience of KDE as well. I don't know what your long terms aims are, but I suggest that, after you've found the DE of your choice, you do a clean install of that and use that for "production" purposes.

Comment: >> How thoroughly did you "replace Unity with LXDE"?

I just installed LXDE as a package from Ubuntu 14.04. I didn't install Lubuntu from the beginning. I don't have much experiences using Lubuntu. The only reason to try out LXDE is that Unity becomes so sluggish..

Comment: >> "notice that you already have an experience of KDE as well.."

Well the only KDE program I'm using is Kate ;)

Comment: Added a sample code for allowing interactive selection of area to be captured by `scrot`.

Comment: Remember to run `openbox --reconfigure` to make Openbox know you've modified `rc.xml`. Also make a backup of rc.xml before you edit it so that you have something to fall back on just in case!

Comment: In my Ubuntu the `rc.xml` file is called `lubuntu-rc.xml`

Comment: Okay, because you mentioned `lxde`, it wasn't clear to me. If you installed `lxde` via `lubuntu-desktop`, the file is `lubuntu-rc.xml` as you noted. I'm using pure Lubuntu rather than Ubuntu + the lubuntu desktop because that's just more economical. As things stand, you'll still get updates to a lot of software you'll probably not be using.